Shell script to backup dir from list
I have a backup script which does the job but takes a long time to complete because it tars Users dir against a list of servers in DEV_Servers.txt  one by one.
Is there a way the tar command could run for the list of servers all at the same time instead of going through the list one by one?
#!/bin/ksh
print  "==========================================="
print  "Taking backup of Users dir"
print  "==========================================="

serverList="DEV_Servers.txt"
while read -r server;
do
    print
    print "==========================================="
    print "Taking Backup of Users:" $server
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n $server "cd /opt/test/ ; tar -zcvf 'Users$(date '+%Y%m%d').tar.gz' Users"
done < "$serverList"


Run the ssh command in the background with & so they all run in parallel. Or use GNU Parallel.

/bin/ksh? Why is your question tagged with bash?

sorry you are right, I should of put shell.

minor nitpick: $(date '+%Y%m%d') is going to return the same result on each pass through the loop (in a worse case scenario you could generate a 2nd/different result when passing midnight); consider running date '+%Y%m%d' once earlier in the script, store in a variable and then reference the variable in the ssh call; if using bash or ksh you can make use of the printf / -v capability, eg: printf -v dt "%(%Y%m%d)T" - the variable dt will now contain the current date (eg, 20241120)

One way to run the tar commands in parallel is by putting each SSH call in the background. You can do this by appending an & at the end of each SSH command. Here's how you can modify your script:
#!/bin/ksh
print "==========================================="
print "Taking backup of Users dir"
print "==========================================="

serverList="DEV_Servers.txt"
while read -r server;
do
    print
    print "==========================================="
    print "Taking Backup of Users:" $server
    # Run tar command in the background
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n $server "cd /opt/test/ ; tar -zcvf 'Users$(date '+%Y%m%d').tar.gz' Users" &
done < "$serverList"

# Wait for all background jobs to finish
wait



The & at the end of the ssh command tells the shell to run the command in the background.
The wait command ensures that the script waits for all background jobs to finish before it exits.


background processes writing to the tty may get suspended. consider using tty -tostop or somesuch, or redirecting the ssh output

Untested:
#!/bin/ksh
print  "==========================================="
print  "Taking backup of Users dir"
print  "==========================================="

serverList="DEV_Servers.txt"

do_one() {
    server="$1"
    print
    print "==========================================="
    print "Taking Backup of Users:" $server
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n "$server" "cd /opt/test/ ; tar -zcvf 'Users$(date '+%Y%m%d').tar.gz' Users"
}
export -f do_one

parallel -j0 do_one < "$serverList"

It requires that ssh server does not ask for a passphrase. If you have set up ssh-agent this should be fine.
